# Does the union of fractional Sobolev spaces fills $L^p$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \Bbb R^d$ be any open set. Recall that for $s\in (0,1)$, the fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ is the collection of function in $L^p(\Omega$ such that
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega\Omega} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}dy d x <\infty. 
\end{align*}

I would like to prove or disprove that   the inclusion $$   \bigcup_{s\in (0, 1)} W^{s,p}(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega)$$ is strict.

In other words there is $u \in L^p(\Omega) \setminus \bigcup_{s\in (0,1)} W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ that is there is $u\in L^p(\Omega) $ such that
\begin{align*}
\iint_{\Omega\Omega} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{d+sp}}dy d x =\infty \qquad \text{for all $s\in (0,1)$}. 
\end{align*}

The assertion is true for $d=1$. Indeed it suffices to consider $\Omega= (0,1)$ and $(a_n)_n\subset (0,1)$ with
\begin{align*}
    a_n= \frac{c}{(n+2)\log^2(n+2)}, 
\end{align*}
be such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1.$

Define the partial sum
$t_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j=1$ so that   $0<t_n<t_{n+1}<1$.  We consider the open set
$O$  be  the disjoint  union of $(t_{2k}, t_{2k+1})$ that is
\begin{align*}
O= \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty (t_{2k}, t_{2k+1})
\qquad\text{so that }\qquad 
(0,1)\setminus O= \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (t_{2k-1}, t_{2k}). 
\end{align*}

It is not difficult to see that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{|1_O(x)-1_O(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{1+sp}}d yd x
\geq 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{t_{2k}}^{t_{2k+1}} \int_{t_{2k+1}}^{t_{2k+2}}\frac{d yd x}{|x-y|^{1+sp}}=\infty. 
\end{align*}

Does this remains true in higher dimension?

Comment: Wouldn't (for $\Omega$ being a cube, say) taking $u(x_1, \ldots , x_d) = g(x_1)g(x_2)\ldots g(x_d)$ work, where $g$ is a one-dimensional counterexample? I also think there should be some cheap and dirty argument with the Banach–Steinhaus theorem, but I'm too lazy to figure it out.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Though I didn't mentioned, I did suspect this extension argument may works. I have not tried it.  But I expected some more skilled artefact from big guys in this rooms.

Comment: Certainly if you have a spectral characterization (as for $p=2$) as weighted $L^2$ spaces (via Fourier/etc transform), this is easily true by constructing suitable sequences/functions on the spectral side.

Comment: Ask your  beginning students in functional analysis to prove that no Banach space is the countable union of operator ranges. If necessary, suggest that they prove first that if $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded non surjective linear operator with $X$ and $Y$ Banach, then the closure in $Y$ of the image of the unit ball of $X$ has empty interior in $Y$  (this is sometimes called the "little open mapping theorem").

Comment: One can also choose countably many disjoint open sets $\Omega_j\subset \Omega$.  Since the family of spaces $W_0^{s,p}(\Omega_j)$ is strictly monotone wrto s, we can put a function $u_j$ with compact support in each $\Omega_j$, so that the resulting $\sum_j u_j$ is in  $L^p$, but in $W^{s,p}(\Omega)$ for no $s\in(0,1)$

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume that  $p=2$, and let us consider
$$
\cup_{s>0} H^s(\mathbb R^d)\subset H^0(\mathbb R^d)=L^2(\mathbb R^d).
$$
The above inclusion is strict. Let us consider $u\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ defined by its Fourier transform,
$$
u_\alpha(x)= \int e^{2iπ x\cdot \xi}(1+\vert \xi\vert)^{-\frac d2}
\bigl(\log(2+\vert \xi\vert)\bigr)^{-\frac\alpha 2} d\xi, \quad \alpha >1.
$$
Now the function $u_\alpha$ does not belong to any $H^s(\mathbb R^d)$ when $s>0$. Otherwise we would have for some $s>0$,
$$
(1+\vert \xi\vert)^{-\frac d2+s}
\bigl(\log(2+\vert \xi\vert)\bigr)^{-\frac\alpha 2}\in L^2(\mathbb R^d),
$$
which is untrue since
$
\int_1^{+\infty} r^{2s-1}(\log(2+r))^{-\alpha}dr=+\infty.
$